# Propensity score estimation with panel data

Tags: panel-data, propensity-scores

I have a panel dataset with data on 3 years (say t-1, t , t+1) and a binary treatment that occurs at t. I plan to conduct a matched diff in diff. as the first step, I use a logit model to calculate the probability of treatment participation based on pre treatment covariates. So basically I run a logit model with dependent variable as the treatment status in t while controlling for covariates (X) in t-1 this gives me a predicted score only for treatment period (t). Should I then copy this score to period t-1 and t+1 for each individual or am I doing something wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also this is my first post on the platform and I apologise for any mistakes in the question.